# Read a .dat File and create an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, coordinates

I try to read a .dat file with a list of coordinates X and Y. My code work to count the lines in the file but it doesn't work to read the coordinates correctly. In the output just show me the number of lines in the .dat file, but it doesn't show me the coordinates. .dat file has 2 column and more than 5 rows (I have many files with different amount of coordinates). Any help is super welcome, i am very new in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    std::vector<int> numbers;

    ifstream fileB;
    const int SIZE=10;
    char filas_dat [SIZE];

    fileB.open("Verticesfixed_cell1slc44.dat");

    std::string line;
    int counter=0;
    while (getline(fileB, line)) //contador de filas
    {
        ++counter;
    }

    if(!fileB.good())
    {
        int current_number = 0;
        while (fileB >> current_number){
            numbers.push_back(current_number);}

        fileB.close();
        cout << "The numbers are: ";
        for (int count = 0; count < numbers.size(); count++){
            cout << numbers[count] << " ";}

        cout << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
       cout << "Error!";
    }
return 0
}
```

Comment: `if(!fileB.good())` is probably not what you really want to check, IMO that should be `if(fileB.good())`. Debugging your code line by line would probably have been faster than formulate a question here.

Comment: .. I concur with user πάντα ῥεῖ that adding a "!" was a bad idea. "fluidics flows"... have a good one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after you've counted the number of lines you are at the end of the file, so there is nothing more to read. A file doesn't reposition itself back to the beginning automatically. You have to tell the file to go back to the beginning.

A second similar problem is that when you get to the end of your file the `getline` function fails (because there's nothing more to read). That puts your file into an *error state* when nothing will work until you clear the error state.

Finally the call to `!fileB.good()` is unecessary. The file will never be good at this point, again this is because `getline` has failed.

Try this code

```
while (getline(fileB, line)) //contador de filas
{
    ++counter;
}
fileB.clear(); // clear the error state
fileB.seekg(0); // go back to the beginning of the file

int current_number = 0;
while (fileB >> current_number)
{
    numbers.push_back(current_number);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It was super useful to understand my problem. Now, it works well!.